# Validating DTD-String with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, libxml2

I am switching from LibXML to Nokogiri. I have a method in my code to check if an xml document matches an Dtd. The Dtd is read from a database (as string).

This is an example within an irb session

```
require 'xml'
doc = LibXML::XML::Document.string('<foo bar="baz" />') #=> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
dtd = LibXML::XML::Dtd.new('<!ELEMENT foo EMPTY><!ATTLIST foo bar ID #REQUIRED>') #=> #<LibXML::XML::Dtd:0x000000026f53b8>
doc.validate dtd #=> true
```

As I understand `#validate` of `Nokogiri::XML::Document` it is only possible to check DTDs within the Document. How would I do this to archive the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `internal_subset`:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<!DOCTYPE html>")
# then you can get the info you want
doc.internal_subset # Nokogiri::XML::DTD

# for example you can get name, system_id, external_id, etc
doc.internal_subset.name
doc.internal_subset.system_id
doc.internal_subset.external_id
```

Here is a full doc of [Nokogiri::XML::DTD](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/DTD.html).

Thanks

Comment: I am not using HTML so this does not work for me. I am creating the document with `Nokogiri::XML('<foo bar="baz" />')` which leaves me with `internal_subset => nil`.